# agregar DevTools Extension a Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Comunidad les agradecería su ayuda.

Estoy intentando implementar el plugin de chrome para React y redux ( Redux DevTools Extension)
el inconveniente es que mi aplicación quedo con esta estructura  y no he podido integrar correctamente la ultima parte que es agregar  el composeWithDevTools.para hacer debbug de los estados de redux.

Estructura actual

```
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import { verifyAuth } from "./actions/";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";



export default function configureStore(persistedState) {
const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 persistedState, 
 applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
 );
store.dispatch(verifyAuth());
return store;
}
```

Segun la [documentacion](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) deberia ser

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

Intente

```
export default function configureStore(persistedState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer ,composeWithDevTools (
    persistedState, 
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),

  )

    );
  store.dispatch(verifyAuth());
  return store;
}
```

Pero me sale este error

```
TypeError: e is not a function
concat.reduceRight.r.instanceId
<anonymous>:1:28778
(anonymous function)
<anonymous>:1:28745
createStore
C:/Desarrollo/haycarta/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:79
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si alguno tiene el mismo problema, lo resolví así

```
export default function configureStore(persistedState) {
  const store = createStore( rootReducer, persistedState, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
  )
    );
  store.dispatch(verifyAuth());
  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra forma que se puede hacer:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
))

export default store;
```